# Why an ad server instead serve the ads from the website server?

Tags: dns, server, subdomain, openx, advertisement-server

I am on the first step to set up openX to serve the ads in my website. Now I have a question.

I have understood it is better to serve the ads from another server instead serve them from the place where I have my website (to reduce the page load time, etc..)

Now my question is:

- Is better to have my own domain instead a subdomain? I mean ads.mysite.com or mysiteads.com and why?

Answer (score 1):

> Is better to have my own domain instead a subdomain? I mean ads.mysite.com or mysiteads.com and why?

I'd go for engine.mysite.com for a simple reason: ad blockers. If you use a completely different domain, it may be flagged by adblock users and be blacklisted any time. By using a subdomain of your website's main domain, ad blockers may allow the ads as they are served from the same domain (blocking your domain would make your whole site unreachable, which is not their intent).

I would use engine.mysite.com instead of ads.mysite.com, as ad blockers may block any 'ad' subdomain (don't make it too easy for them to figure out what that subdomain does :))

Answer (score 0):

I would block your site through our proxy server so if you were to serve ads from a different domain I would be less likely to have your actual domain blocked.

Comment: I don't get what you mean! why would you block my site if I serve ads from a different domain? This is a valid/usual technic, example: Facebook uses this domain fbcdn.net to serve ads instead facebook.com

Comment: I would block the ad site so if it is your domain your entire site would be blocked. Facebook also server CSS content from fbcdn so the site looks terrible with that domain blocked. I would not use Facebook as an example of valid web coding when it is completely inaccessible without CSS.